# Ler e escrever structs em C

Tags: c, loop, struct, binary

Estou a fazer um programa que recebe um numero indeterminado de structs e que os guarda num ficheiro binario, um de cada vez, e depois usa outra função para ver todos os structs dentro desse ficheiro.

De momento sempre que eu corro a função lista, ou acontece um loop infinito, ou aparece apenas o ultimo struct que eu registei, ao inves de aparecer a lista toda de carros introduzidos.

```
    struct Carro
    {
        char Marca[30];
        char Modelo[30];
        char Cor[30];
        int Numero;
     } ficha;

void LISTA()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("dados.bin","rb");
    printf("\n\t\tLista\n");

     fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);   
    while(fread(&ficha, sizeof(ficha), 1 ,fp) )
    {
        printf ("\nID: %d \nMarca: %s\nModelo: %s\nCor: %s\n\n", ficha.Numero, ficha.Marca, ficha.Modelo, ficha.Cor);
    }

    fclose (fp); 


}

  void INSERIR ()
{

  FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("dados.bin", "wb");


    printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
    printf("\n\n\nID:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &ficha.Numero);


system("CLS");

int marca;
    printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
    printf("\nMarca:");
    printf("\n\n1 - Aston Martin\n2 - Bentley\n3 - Jaguar\n\nSeleção -> ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &marca);


    while((marca < 1) || (marca >3))
    {
        printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", & marca);
    }   


    switch(marca)
    {
        case 1:
            strcpy(ficha.Marca, "Aston Martin");
                system("CLS");
                int modelo = 0;
                    printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                    printf("\nModelo:");
                    printf("\n\n1 - New Vantage\n2 - Vanquish S\n\nSeleção -> ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%d", &modelo);


                    while((modelo < 1) || (modelo >2))
                    {
                        printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d", &modelo);
                    }   


                    switch(modelo)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            strcpy(ficha.Modelo, "New Vantage");
                                system("CLS");
                                int cor = 0;
                                printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                                printf("\nCor:");
                                printf("\n\n1 - Skyfall Silver\n2 - Ultramarine Black\n\nSeleção -> ");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d", &cor);


                                while((cor < 1) || (cor >2))
                                {
                                    printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    scanf("%d", &cor);
                                }   


                                switch(cor)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Skyfall Silver");
                                    break;

                                    case 2:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Ultramarine Black");
                                    break;

                                }

                        break;

                        case 2:
                            strcpy(ficha.Modelo, "Vanquish S");
                                system("CLS");
                                int cor2 = 0;
                                printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                                printf("\nCor:");
                                printf("\n\n1 - Skyfall Silver\n2 - Ultramarine Black\n\nSeleção -> ");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d", &cor2);


                                while((cor2 < 1) || (cor2 >2))
                                {
                                    printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    scanf("%d", &cor2);
                                }   


                                switch(cor2)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Skyfall Silver");
                                    break;

                                    case 2:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Ultramarine Black");
                                    break;

                                }

                        break;

                    }


        break;

        case 2:
            strcpy(ficha.Marca, "Bentley");
                system("CLS");
                int modelo2 = 0;
                    printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                    printf("\nModelo:");
                    printf("\n\n1 - Bentayga\n2 - New Continental GT\n\nSeleção -> ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%d", &modelo2);


                    while((modelo2 < 1) || (modelo2 >2))
                    {
                        printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d", &modelo2);
                    }   


                    switch(modelo2)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            strcpy(ficha.Modelo, "Bentayga");
                            system("CLS");
                                int cor3 = 0;
                                printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                                printf("\nCor:");
                                printf("\n\n1 - Black Crystal\n2 - Magnetic\n\nSeleção -> ");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d", &cor3);


                                while((cor3 < 1) || (cor3 >2))
                                {
                                    printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    scanf("%d", &cor3);
                                }   


                                switch(cor3)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Black Crystal");
                                    break;

                                    case 2:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Magnetic");
                                    break;

                                }

                        break;


                        case 2:
                            strcpy(ficha.Modelo, "New Continental GT");
                            system("CLS");
                                int cor4 = 0;
                                printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                                printf("\nCor:");
                                printf("\n\n1 - Black Crystal\n2 - Magnetic\n\nSeleção -> ");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d", &cor4);


                                while((cor4 < 1) || (cor4 >2))
                                {
                                    printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    scanf("%d", &cor4);
                                }   


                                switch(cor4)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Black Crystal");
                                    break;

                                    case 2:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Magnetic");
                                    break;

                                }

                        break;

                    }

        break;

        case 3:
            strcpy(ficha.Marca, "Jaguar");
                system("CLS");
                int modelo3 = 0;
                    printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                    printf("\nModelo:");
                    printf("\n\n1 - F-Type\n2 - XE\n\nSeleção -> ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%d", &modelo3);


                    while((modelo3 < 1) || (modelo3 >2))
                    {
                        printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d", &modelo3);
                    }   


                    switch(modelo3)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            strcpy(ficha.Modelo, "F-Type");

                            system("CLS");
                                int cor5 = 0;
                                printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                                printf("\nCor:");
                                printf("\n\n1 - Portofino Blue\n2 - Santorini Black\n\nSeleção -> ");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d", &cor5);


                                while((cor5 < 1) || (cor5 >2))
                                {
                                    printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    scanf("%d", &cor5);
                                }   


                                switch(cor5)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Portofino Blue");
                                    break;

                                    case 2:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Santorini Black");
                                    break;

                                }


                        break;

                        case 2:
                            strcpy(ficha.Modelo, "XE");

                            system("CLS");
                                int cor6 = 0;
                                printf("\n\tIntroduza o novo automóvel:");
                                printf("\nCor:");
                                printf("\n\n1 - Caldera Red\n2 - Santorini Black\n\nSeleção -> ");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d", &cor6);


                                while((cor6 < 1) || (cor6 >2))
                                {
                                    printf("Valor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
                                    fflush(stdin);
                                    scanf("%d", &cor6);
                                }   


                                switch(cor6)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Caldera Red");
                                    break;

                                    case 2:
                                        strcpy(ficha.Cor, "Santorini Black");
                                    break;

                                }


                        break;

                    }

        break;

    }


fwrite(&ficha, sizeof(struct Carro), 1 , fp);
fclose(fp); 

int end = 0;
printf("\n\nCarro Registado com sucesso!\n\nID: %d\nMarca: %s\nModelo: %s\nCor: %s\n\n1 - Menu\n2 - Sair\n\n-> ", ficha.Numero, ficha.Marca, ficha.Modelo, ficha.Cor);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &end);


    while((end < 1) || (end >2))
    {
        printf("\nValor errado. Selecione novamente: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &end);
    }   
if(end == 1)
{
        system("CLS");
        main();
}
else
{
    system("CLS");

}

}
```

Comment: O nosso idioma é o português, portanto, por favor traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Você grava a struct passando como parâmetro para sizeof `struct Carro` mas lê usando `ficha`. Tenta ler também usando `sizeof(struct Carro)` e vê no que dá...